# Extracting displacy (spacy) output depenedency connections

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy

I am using the displacy visualization tool from spacy to look at dependencies between words in a sentence. It looks like this:

```html
text = 'European authorities fined Google a record $5.1 billion on Wednesday for abusing its power in the mobile phone market and ordered the company to alter its practices
print(displacy.render(nlp(text), jupyter=True, style='ent'))
print(displacy.render(nlp(text), style='dep', jupyter = True, options = {'distance': 120}))
```

[image]

Is there anyway to extract the connections that the arrows are makingby indexing the words in the string? For example, in the image below, look at the connections in 'European Authorities fined Google'. Anyway to make the following dataframe (each word in the word column, and each word that word connects to in the connection column)?:

```
word       |   connection
---------------------------
European   |   
Authorities| European
fined      | Authorities, Google, record, ..., ...
Google     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacy [provides](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes) a lot of attributes that you can use for this purpose like [ancestors](https://spacy.io/api/token#ancestors) or [children](https://spacy.io/api/token#children). Note that these attributes return generators hence the need to cast them to lists then a string

Here is an example where I used the *children* attribute

```py
text = 'European authorities fined Google a record $5.1 billion on Wednesday for abusing its power in the mobile phone market and ordered the company to alter its practices'
doc = nlp(text)
words = []
a_network = []
for w in doc:
  words.append(w)
  network = [t.text for t in list(w.children)]
  a_network.append(", ".join(network))

df = pd.DataFrame({"word":words,"network":a_network})

print(df)
```

The output would be

```
           word                               network
0      European                                      
1   authorities                              European
2         fined  authorities, Google, record, on, for
3        Google                                      
4             a                                      
5        record                            a, billion
6             $                                      
7           5.1                                      
8       billion                                $, 5.1
...
```